# Is there a tool or script for Windows XP to directly switch users when logged on

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts, switch

I use currently fast user switching, which is ok in the sense that it doesn't require the current user to log off. However, switching users is a bit cumbersome as it involves four steps:

1. clicking start
2. click log off
3. click switch user
4. on the start sceen, click the icon for the other user

I'd like to reduce the number of steps to one, i.e. clicking an icon on the quick launch bar to directly switch to a certain user. Is this doable with some internal or external tool, or a script?

Answer (score 4):

Windows Key + L will cut the number of steps in half. :)

Comment: close, but still one step short :) +1 anyway

Comment: That final step is all down to authenticating to be who you say you are...

Answer (score 2):

%SystemRoot%\System32\Tsdiscon.exe

will take you straight to the 'Switch User' screen if that helps any.